# Use a defined variable in SELECT leads to Incorrect Syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have declared a variable that gives me an integer number:

Let's say the variable is defined like this:

```
DECLARE @mynumber int;
SET @mynumber = 15;
```

And now I would like to use this number in a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP @mynumber * 
FROM mytable;
```

And I get an error that says:

> Incorrect syntax near @mynumber

How can I run my query so that it will work like

```
SELECT TOP 15 * FROM mytable;
```

?

Comment: @conan does not work.

Comment: @Pedram It should work in later versions of SQL Server, perhaps not in 2000.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that is exactly the problem. it does not work in sql server 2000.

Comment: @Pedram Ok, I figured. Since SQL Server 2000 went out of even extended support earlier this year and shouldn't be used for production, it's hard to find to test with :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may simply try like this:

```
SELECT TOP(@mynumber) * 
FROM mytable;
```

You may check [Retrieving the First N Records from a SQL Query](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417081325/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070605-1.shtml) for details

For older version like SQL Server 2000 you can use ROWCOUNT as like

```
SET ROWCOUNT @mynumber
SELECT * FROM MyTable
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: @Pedram:- I have updated my answer. Does that help now? ROWCOUNT is one way which you can use to achieve what you want!

Comment: you can do magic. thank you! i really hate sql server 2000. my client should change it asap.